# Input string was not in correct format

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2

Im trying to get data from a mysql database and display it in an mvc view.  I am getting the following error -

```
Input string 'N/' was not in the correct format.
```

I have the field that is being queried mapped as a string.  Is the "/" character not allowed?  That field is not even being displayed in the view.
I can run the query that is erroring just fine from mysql workbench and get the results that I expect.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why I am getting this error?  Does the "/" have to be escaped?
Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - I was looking at the wrong mapping file.  sorry for any confusion.